# Strange behaviour in continuous form

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of employees with names and two surnames (in Spain two surnames are required).

To avoid erroneous entries, I have ONE surname table called "ST_JLE_Apellidos". In this way, what I store is the surname number, not the surname itself.

To feed the form I use the following SQL string (Where Table "Apellido2" is an instance of Table "Apellido1":

```
SELECT
  JLE_Personal.Id_Personal_Personal,
  JLE_Personal.Personal_NIF,
  Apellido1.Personal_Apellido,
  Apellido2.Personal_Apellido,
  ST_JLE_Personal_Nombres.Personal_Nombre,
  ST_JLE_CargosEnLaEmpresa.CargosEnLaEmpresa_CargoEnLaEmpresa,
  ST_JLE_Municipios.Municipios_Municipio,
  ST_JLE_Provincias.Provincias_Provincia,
  ST_JLE_Paises.Paises_NombreCast,
  JLE_Personal.Personal_Alta_FechaInicial,
  JLE_Personal.Personal_Alta_FechaFinal
FROM
  ST_JLE_Personal_Apellidos AS Apellido2
  INNER JOIN (
    ST_JLE_Personal_Apellidos AS Apellido1
    INNER JOIN (
      (
        ST_JLE_Paises
        INNER JOIN ST_JLE_Provincias ON ST_JLE_Paises.Id_Paises_Pais = ST_JLE_Provincias.Cod_Provincias_Pais
      )
      INNER JOIN (
        ST_JLE_Municipios
        INNER JOIN (
          ST_JLE_CargosEnLaEmpresa
          INNER JOIN (
            ST_JLE_Personal_Nombres
            INNER JOIN JLE_Personal ON ST_JLE_Personal_Nombres.Id_Personal_Nombre = JLE_Personal.Cod_Personal_Nombre
          ) ON ST_JLE_CargosEnLaEmpresa.Id_CargosEnLaEmpresa_CargoEnLaEmpresa = JLE_Personal.Cod_Personal_Cargo
        ) ON ST_JLE_Municipios.Id_Municipios_Municipio = JLE_Personal.Cod_Personal_Municipio
      ) ON ST_JLE_Provincias.Id_Provincias_Provincia = ST_JLE_Municipios.Cod_Municipios_Provincia
    ) ON Apellido1.Id_Personal_Apellido = JLE_Personal.Cod_Personal_Apellido1
  ) ON Apellido2.Id_Personal_Apellido = JLE_Personal.Cod_Personal_Apellido2;
```

Here is the MS-Access graphic window of the query:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

Everything correct so far.

The problem comes when I try to use a continuous form that contains the two last names:

TextBox  1:  Apellido1.Personal_Apellido
TextBox  2:  Apellido2.Personal_Apellido

[image]

MS-Access accepts both text boxes, but when I run the form, then Text Box 2 automatically changes to Apellido1.Personal_Apellido:

[image]

What could be the mistake that I am making?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a lookup table for surnames? So if you have 10 people last name Smith, you save record ID from Surnames table instead of actually entering "Smith" into employee's record? Never seen this approach taken.

Comment: Recommend not including lookup table in form RecordSource. Use comboboxes instead of textboxes.

Comment: So is. With that, I avoid that a person can write a last name as he wants. I am trying to fix a table that has around 10,000 bad records for that reason..


The question was: why does it work in query preview and not in the form?

Comment: I have encountered this before but cannot remember any other fix than already suggested.

Comment: try a work around.  Access bugs when queries are complicated.  if the query shows the correct data, then turn it into a make table query.  then base the form on the table.

Comment: Confirmed: it's an Access Bug. "Another" Access bug.